# Managing Server Side Events with a Service Worker

Tags: service-worker, server-sent-events

I am building a web app to display on my iPad to control my raspberry pi acting as an audio recorder. Part of the need is to maintain an event source open so that the server can send Server Side Events.  A specific instance of the app can grab control of the recording process, but will loose control if the server sees sse link closes.  This is just protection against a client disappearing and leaving the control held (control of the process does needed to be renewed at least every 5 minutes - but I don't really want to wait that long in the normal case of someone just closing the browser tab.)

Part of my need is to push the browser to the background so I can then open up the camera and record a video.

I built this app and had it almost working see https://github.com/akc42/pi_record.git (master branch).
Until I pushed the browser to the background and found IOS shut down the page and broke the sse link.

I tried restructuring to use a private web worker to manage the sse link, massing messages between the web worker and the main javascript thread - again almost working (see workers branch of above repository).  But that got shutdown too!

My last thought is to use a service worker, but how to structure the app?

Clearly the service worker must act as a client to the server for the server side events.  It must keep the connection open, but it also needs to keep track of multiple tabs in the browser which may or may not try and grab control of the interface, and only allow one tab to do so.

I can think of three approaches - but its difficult to see which is better.  At least I have never even seen any mention of approach 2 and 3 below , but it seems to me that one of these two  might actually be the simplest.

**Approach 1**

Move the code I have now for separate web workers into the service worker.  However we will need to add to the message passing some form of ID between window and service.  So I can record which tab actually grabbed control of the interface and therefore exclude other tabs from doing so (ie simulate a failed attempt to take control).

As far as I can work out MessageEvent.ports[0] could be a unique object which I could store in a Map somewhere, but I am not entirely convinced that the MessageChannel wouldn't close if the browser moved to the background.

**Approach 2**

have a set of phantom urls in the service worker that simulate all the different message types (and parameters) that where previously sent my the tab to its private web worker.

The fetch event provides a clientid (which I can use to difference between who actually grabbed control) and which I can use to then do `Clients.get(clientid).postMessage()` (or `Clients.matchAll` when a broadcast response is needed)

Code would be something like

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', (event) => {

  const requestURL = new URL(event.request.url);
  if (/^\/api\//.test(requestURL.pathname)) {
    event.respondWith(fetch(event.request));  //all api requests are a direct pass through
  } else if (/^\/service\//.test(requestURL.pathname)) {
    /*
      process these like a message passing with one extra to say the client is going away.

    */
    if (urlRecognised) {
      event.respondWith(new Response('OK', {status: 200}));
    } else {
      event.respondWith(new Response(`Unknown request ${requestURL.pathname}`, {status: 404}));
    }
  } else {
    event.respondWith(async () => {
      const cache = await caches.open('recorder');
      const cachedResponse = await cache.match(event.request);
      const networkResponsePromise = fetch(event.request);

      event.waitUntil(async () => {
        const networkResponse = await networkResponsePromise;
        await cache.put(event.request, networkResponse.clone());
      });

      // Returned the cached response if we have one, otherwise return the network response.
      return cachedResponse || networkResponsePromise;

    });
  }
});
```

The top of the the fetch event just passes the standard api requests made by the client straight through.  I can't cache these (although I could be more sophisticated and perhaps pre reject those not supported).
The second section matches phantom urls `/service/something`

The last section is taken from Jake Archibald's offline cookbook and tries to use the cache, but updates the cache in the background if any of the static files have changed.

**Approach 3**

Similar to the approach above, in that we would have phantom urls and use the clientid as a unique marker, but actually try and simulate a server side event stream with one url.

I'm thinking the code with be more like

```
...
 } else if (/^\/service\//.test(requestURL.pathname)) {
   const stream = new TransformStream();
   const writer = stream.writeable.getWriter();
   event.respondWith(async () => {
    const streamFinishedPromise = new Promise(async (resolve,reject) => {
      event.waitUntil(async () => {
        /* eventually close the link  */
        await streamFinishedPromise;
      });
      try {
        while (true) writer.write(await nextMessageFromServerSideEventStream());
      } catch(e) {
        writer.close();
        resolve();
      }
    });
    return new Response(stream.readable,{status:200}) //probably need eventstream headers too 

 }
```

I am thinking that **approach 2** could be the simplest, given where I am now but I am concerned that I can see nothing when searching for how to use service workers that discusses this phantom url approach.

Can anyone comment on any of these approaches and provide guidance on how to best program the tricky bits (for instance does Approach 1 message channel close when the browser is moved to the background on an iPad, or how do you really keep a response channel open, and does that get closed when the browser moves to the background in Approach 3)

Comment: Wouldn't using a shared worker work now ?
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SharedWorker

Comment: @cassepipe I suppose it might.  It looks like Safari only introduced the capability September 2022 and I asked this question in April 2020.  I got the code working and basically haven't touched it since.  I'm busy with another project right now, but I'll add a task to investigate in my github issue list'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple truth is that none of these approaches will work.  What I didn't realise when I asked the question is that a service worker is re-run by the browser when ever there is something to do and that run only lasts for the length of time of the processing of an event.  Although `eventWaitUntil` can prolong that, the only reference to how long I can find is that the browser is still at liberty to cancel it if it appears it might never close.  I can't imagine than in a period of several hours it won't get cancelled.  So an Event Source will close effectively terminate its link to the server.

So my only option to achieve what I want is to have the server carry on when the Event Source closes and find some other mechanism to release resources held on behalf of the client

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I have a fairly similar problem that I'm trying to figure out. One alternative that I am considering is using the Push API (which works with Service Workers and, presumably works when the browser is minimized/closed (because that's pretty much the entire point of Web Push Notifications). 

The only problem is that Safari doesn't quite yet support Push Notifications, but that should be coming soon.

Comment: I think I just allowed the client cookie to timeout after about 4 hours of no contact (otherwise its refreshed on every server interaction).  Service worker just caches static resources and does little else.  I'm not sure because its a year since I touched the code

Comment: Thanks! Though I don't quite follow how the cookie is used to maintain/renew a connection from within a service worker once it shuts down... Or am I missing something? I'll probably end up changing my requirement for receiving messages in the background and just do SSE from SharedWorker or just separate WebWorkers per tab.